# Why this question is off-topic?

Tags: discussion

[Given an even function how to obtain the most close odd function and vise versa?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159330/given-an-even-function-how-to-obtain-the-most-close-odd-function-and-vise-versa)

Why it was closed?

Comment: Now I want to answer this question myself, at least it covers a large set of functions.

Answer (score 5):

I hadn't seen the question until just now, nor have I tried to follow what you're asking mathematically.  But the comments express some pretty clear objections.  "Off-topic" seems like an inappropriate closure reason, but then, the list of options doesn't always contain what we want.

As Scott says, it's not helpful that you've deleted your own comments, because (for instance) it makes it harder to answer your question above.

Let me also agree with Yemon: you need to clarify what you mean by "function", otherwise the question isn't precise.  I suppose you mean something like "Lebesgue-integrable function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$", but don't make us guess: tell us!

Comment: I already clarified what functions I consider: those equal to their Newton series.

Comment: Yes, and that improves the question.  But: (1) you still use the word "function" for two paragraphs before you impose this restriction (so it remains unclear what you mean by "function" in the abstract); (2) it wouldn't hurt for you to tell us the domain and codomain; and (3) does discrete-analytic imply integrable, or is integrability something you're silently assuming?  I wasn't one of the closers, so understand this for what it is: an attempt to help you understand why it was closed.  That's what you asked for.

Comment: How is it possible to get a reputation of 1,655 in MO by asking three questions with votes {0,-3,-11} and giving one answer with votes -7 ? Cf. http://meta.mathoverflow.net/users/10059/anixx I am amazed!

Comment: @TaQ how is it possible to a get a reputation of 927 with 0 answers and 0 questions? ;-) More seriously, the link you give is to the **meta** user of OP; these are thus his meta contributions that have nothing to do with the repuation on the main site. [Footnote: Actually it would be  possible to get 927 without answers and questions, via suggested edits, but this is capped at 1000.] Other than that I find your rather negative comment a bit unnecessary.

Comment: @ quid: OK. I didn't notice the difference. Sorry.